# Why use fabs() rather than casting?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, having learnt Java previously.  What I'm struggling to understand is why use `fabs()` function (from `<cmath>`).  I understand what fabs does, it's to get the absolute value of a number (i.e. more precision).  However, can you not just do it as in Java:

```
int x = 1;
float x = (float) x;
```

What is the benefit in using `fabs()` function, rather than just casting?

Comment: absolute value does NOT mean more precision.

Comment: The first thing you have to learn when it comes to programming with numbers: You can never get more precision out of thin air.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you don't *entirely* understand what `fabs` does - it returns the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number, i.e. `y = |x|`. So if `x` is positive it just returns `x`, but if `x` is negative if returns `-x`:

```
float x = 1.0f;
float y = abs(x); // y = x = 1.0f

float x = -1.0f;
float y = abs(x); // x = -1.0f, y = 1.0f
```